# Excel script/functions to sum columns for rows with matching values?

Tags: excel

I have a table that looks like this:

```
**Item Name           Quantity     Total**
Item A                   1           1
Item B                   8           
Item B                   4           
Item B                   47          59
Item C                   8           8
Item D                   3           
Item D                   19          22
```

I want to get the total quantity for every item in some automatic way, but each item is in multiple rows, with separate quantities listed in the next column.

Currently I'm sorting by item name, selecting a cell next to the item, and writing "=sum", then selecting the range. However there are hundreds of items in this document and it usually takes a few hours to do it this way.

To recap:
Every item exists in 1 or more rows. Each row has the item name and a quantity. For each item name, I need the sum of all quantity values from all rows with the matching name.

Comment: You can use `SUMIF()`

Comment: Maybe it's a time to take a look at **[EXCEL VBA](http://www.excel-pratique.com/fr/vba.php)**, you can do what you want using simple vba macro.

Comment: Best way is to create a pivot table. The setup takes less than a minute and every time you add additional data, all you have to do is refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what [Pivot tables](http://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html) were made for. You can use a simple wizard to get totals for all of your items in a collapsed way. It won't show in column C like your example, but it will easily organize your data.

Basically wherever you put your table will show

```
Item A : 1 
Item B : 59
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick! Add this somewhere else in your sheet and change the ranges accordingly.

```
       +--------+------------------------+ 
       | Totals |  Formula               |
       +--------+------------------------+ 
A10 -->| Item A | =SUMIF(A2:A8,A10,B2:B8)|
A11 -->| Item B | =SUMIF(A2:A8,A11,B2:B8)|
A12 -->| Item C | =SUMIF(A2:A8,A12,B2:B8)|
A13 -->| Item D | =SUMIF(A2:A8,A13,B2:B8)|
       +--------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I think this is not practical for this case because there are hundreds of items in document just like mentioned in question.

Comment: You don't need to hard-code "Item A" etc in the formula - link to the first column instead.    `=SUMIF(A2:A8, A2, B2:B8)` etc

Comment: Hi Tim, I looked at Sumif for this problem and also thought it was impractical because I couldn't find a way to automatically update the reference depending on what name was in the item cell.

Are you saying I can put that formula into one cell, drag it down the sheet, and each box will have the sum of all items matching the item column?

Comment: @Catma, I've updated the answer accordingly to Tim's suggestion. You're correct in that you should be able to just drag the formula cell afterwards